# Python batch google sheet update

Tags: python, google-sheets

I would like to update 2 columns as on the attached screenshot

I dont have any problems with a single cell

```py
range_attempts = ledger!E35

values = [
    [
        attempts
    ],
]

Body = {
    'values': values,
}

response = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range=range_attempts,
    valueInputOption='RAW', body=Body).execute()
```

But find it difficult to use `batchUpdate`

How could I define a range for 2 columns, given that I am going to set all cells to the same value = 0

[image]

**SOLUTION**

use: **'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS'**

```
range_reset = ledger_name + '!' + "E3:E203"

val = []
for _ in range(200):
    val.append("0")

values = [
    val,
]

Body = {
   'values': values,
   'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS'
}
```

Comment: If "SOLUTION" answers your question, please post it as an _answer_

Answer (score 1):

use: **'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS'**

```
range_reset = ledger_name + '!' + "E3:E203"

val = []
for _ in range(200):
    val.append("0")

values = [
    val,
]

Body = {
   'values': values,
   'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS'
}
```